# how do I display "how many days ago a user visited a website" in PHP

Tags: php

I want to display how many days/hours/minutes/seconds ago a user last visited the website. I'm new to cookies and can't get to make them work.

Edit: Right now `$lastVisit` and `$thisVisit` are the same, how would i make them separate?

Here's my code so far (I know it's doing nothing close to what it's supposed to do):

```php
<?php
    
    if(isset($_COOKIE['LastCookie']))
    {
        $lastVisit = $_COOKIE['LastCookie'];
        $inOneMonth = time() + (60*60*24*30);
        setcookie('LastCookie', time(), $inOneMonth);
        $thisVisit = $_COOKIE['LastCookie'];
?>
        <html>
            <head>
                <title>Cookie Exercise</title>
            </head>
            <body>
                <p> Your last visit was before: </br /></p>
                <?php 
                    echo $lastVisit."<br />"; 
                    $diff = $thisVisit - $lastVisit;
                    $seconds = $diff % 60;
                    $minutes = $seconds % 60;
                    $hours = $minutes % 60;
                    $days = $hours % 24;
                    echo "Diff: $diff <br /> $days $hours $minutes $seconds";
                ?>
            </body>
        </html>
<?php    
    }
    else 
    {
        setcookie('LastCookie', time(), time() + (60*60*24*30));
?>
        <html>
            <head>
                <title>Cookie Exercise</title>
            </head>
            <body>
                <p> This is your first visit to this website </br /></p>
                
            </body>
        </html>
<?php 
    }
 ?>
```

Here's the exercise I'm trying to do incase my explaination wasn't clear:
[image: 1]

Comment: So, your exercise suggests you use "division/modulus, floor", which you haven't yet. But if you're having problems with the cookie part, we shouldn't be reading your homework anyway - always break down the problem to the smallest relevant parts, and get them right before moving on. So, is the cookie being set at all? What actually is your current output?

Comment: i think the main issue is i cant differentiate last visit and this visit, I've updated my code since i asked the question, let me edit the code in question

Comment: The big problem I see here is using a cookie. Cookies can be deleted and many users clean their history so detecting a revisit by cookie is impracitcal. I would log users in a MYSQL table according to their IP address and add a timestamp column.

Comment: it was just an exercise to do with cookies :D

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have this condition:

> ```
> if(isset($_COOKIE['LastCookie']))
> ```

As a prerequisite to this line of code:

> ```
> setcookie('LastCookie', time(), $inOneMonth);
> ```

… so you only ever update an **existing** cookie. You never set a new one if this is the first visit.

You need to calculate `$lastVisit` if the cookie is set, but **set** the new cookie regardless (outside of the condition).

Comment: thanks for helping
i think the main issue is i cant differentiate last visit and this visit, I've updated and editted my code since i asked the question.

Comment: @FiveNine — If you have a new question, then don't edit an existing question to invalidate answers people have given you. Ask a new question.

Answer (score 0):

As i see, you don't set the cookie, you just check if the cookie exists.

To save a cookie use `setcookie`:

```
setcookie('test', 'Hello!', time()+(60*60*24), '/');
```

This function will set a cookie with the name `test` and the value `Hello!` expiring 24 hours after the cookie was set. The `/` at the end is the path. Use `/`, if you want to access the cookie on your whole page, use for example `/test/` if you only want to use it in the `test` directory.

Use `isset()` to check, if a cookie already exists:

```
if( isset($_COOKIE['test']) ) {
   // Cookie exists
}
```

To get the cookie's content, use:

```
$test = $_COOKIE['test'];
```

If you want to update the expiration date, just overwrite the current cookie with the `setcookie()` function.

That's also how to delete a cookie, just set the expiration date lower than the current timestamp.

Comment: You don't have to call `session_start` before use cookie.

Comment: Thanks @shingo, i edited my answer. I thought `session_start` is needed.